# R: error downloading shapefiles with download.file() and opening them with readRDS()

Tags: r, download

I'm trying to download spatial polygons here:

http://www.gadm.org/country

and I want to download almost all countries in different dimensions (regional, national, subregional) so more files than I'd like to download manually.

This little loop [stone him! he used the l word!] does the trick with two small island national polygons as examples:

```
countries <- c("CYM", "BMU")
mypath <- "C:/Desktop/" # please change this 
for(i in countries){
download.file(paste0("http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2.8/rds/",i,"_adm0.rds"),
          destfile=paste0(mypath,i,"_adm0.rds"))
}
```

the problem is that when I now try to read this data into R, I get the following errors:

```
nationalpolygon <- readRDS(paste0(mypath,"CYM_adm0.rds"))

Error in readRDS("C:/Desktop/CYM_adm0.rds") : 
error reading from connection
In addition: Warning message:
In readRDS("C:/Desktop/CYM_adm0.rds") :
invalid or incomplete compressed data
```

It works perfectly, however, if I download the data manually into the same folder so I'm guessing I'm missing something in donwload.file? Without understanding them, I tried to play around with the options there but that did not help. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try using `mode="wb"` inside `download.file()`

Comment: hm, I thought I had tried that but in any case, now it works.